# How to prevent UITableView from scrolling up on endUpdates() when setContentOffset was used before?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I use `tableView.setContentOffset(...)` to move a cell holding a `UITextView` above the keyboard when the TextView becomes first responder. If this content offset is outside the range the user can normally scroll to, calling `beginUpdates() ... endUpdates()` in this state will cause the TableView to scroll back to a *normal* contenOffset.

**How to prevent this?**

---

#### Details

- A simple `UIViewController` holding a `UITableView`
- The bottom most cell of the TableView contains a `UITextView`
- When the TextField becomes the first responder the TextView/Cell should of course be moved above the keyboard. I found some information that iOS / the TableView should handle this itself but it does not (am I doing something wrong?)
- So I handle `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` to get information about the keyboard frame and set the contenOffset manually to move the TextView cell above the keyboard.
- It would not be possible for the user to scroll to this contentOffset but setting it manually is no problem.
- The cell height should adapt to the TextView height when multiple lines are entered. So I call `beginUpdates() ... endUpdates()` to let the TabelView update the cell height.
- This update triggers the TableView to reset its position and to scroll back to a *normal* contentOffset which shows the cell at the bottom of and thus behind the keyboard.

#### How to reproduce

Of course the problem can be reproduced creating the setup described above. But a simpler solution is possible as well

- `UITableView` with some random content
- ButtonA sets a contentOffset which is outside the *normal* scrolling range
- ButtonB calls `beginUpdates() ... endUpdates()`
- ==> Try to prevent the TableView from scrolling and to keep the same contentOffset as before the update...

#### What did NOT work

In other questions I found the following solutions but none of them worked:

```
// Disable animations before update ==> No effect
let contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)

self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()

UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
self.tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)


// Remove layer animation after update ==> No effect
let contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset

self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()

self.tableView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
self.tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
```